# Where should I configure DNS in Debian 11?

Tags: debian, networking, dns, resolv.conf

I'm using Debian 11 (Bullseye). I'd like to use a different DNS server. I found the file `/etc/resolv.conf`. It looks like this (by default):

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Fair enough default. Use the local router/gateways DNS, then Cloudflare, followed by Google's DNS. There is a second file, too, though - `/etc/network/interfaces`. For me, where is what it looks like by default (I'm using DHCP)

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug enp4s0f0
iface enp4s0f0 inet dhcp
```

In that file, I can set my preferred DNS there by saying this, if I wanted to use, say, [quad9](https://www.quad9.net/) for my DNS.

```
dns-nameservers 9.9.9.9
```

So, if I'd like to change my DNS server, which file do I need to edit? Just one? Both?

Comment: I used this guide: https://www.ricmedia.com/set-permanent-dns-nameservers-ubuntu-debian-resolv-conf/

Comment: Check the timestamp of your `/etc/resolv.conf` file. If the file gets overwritten at boot, you are most likely getting your DNS settings over DHCP and you will need to configure your DHCP client to override the values specified by the DHCP server.  How to do that depends on whether you're using a net config management system like NetworkManager or not, and which DHCP client are you using (`dhclient`? `dhcpcd`? `pump`?)

Answer (score 8):

The [Debian wiki for `resolv.conf`](https://wiki.debian.org/resolv.conf) explains how the dns-nameserver address is configured:

1. Debian reads the `nameserver` address from `/etc/resolv.conf`.
2. `/etc/resolv.conf` may be dynamically generated by either **resolvconf** or **openresolv**.
3. **openresolv** reads its configuration from `/etc/resolvconf.conf`.
4. **resolvconf** reads the `dns-nameserver 0.0.0.0` configuration inside `/etc/network/interfaces` via **ifupdown**.

---

A vanilla Debian installation has has neither **resolvconf** or **openresolv** installed. Therefore your options are either to:

1. Configure the `nameserver` configuration directly in /etc/resolv.conf.
2. Install **openresolv** and then configure `dns-nameserver` in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

---

To see which package, if either, is installed on your system, do...

```
$ sudo apt list --installed | grep resolvconf
$ sudo apt list --installed | grep openresolv
```

To check what nameserver your system is currently using, do...

```
$ dig example.org | grep SERVER
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also configure dhclient to prepend your DNS nameserver list without installing additional services.

Add this line to /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf

```
prepend domain-name-servers 1.1.1.1, 1.1.0.0, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
```

Then restart your box. The above DNS servers should be prepended above your routers DNS server in the /etc/resolv.conf after reboot.

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
domain lan
search lan
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.1.0.0
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

Running dig google.com should show the box using the first DNS server from the list above in the SERVER section:

```
$ dig google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.18.24-1-Debian <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 53711
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             227     IN      A       142.250.217.238

;; Query time: 20 msec
;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Mon Mar 18 19:26:55 EDT 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55
```